# Highlight specific image on page loads

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have three activities and in my first activity i have 2 imageviews , by clicking each image it is navigating to the next activities. All the three activities contains imageviews. Now my problem is when navigating to the next activity on click, default image is getting highlighted, instead i would like to highlight a specific image of my choice.Help me in achieving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the ans.. It is very simple we need to set request focus on the particular image

```
img1.requestFocus();
```

near particular onclick. Hope this may help someone :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting setColorFilter to your view. You can highlight the your specific view.

```
PorterDuffColorFilter setNewFilter = 
new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

ImageView imgSelected = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImage);
Drawable d = imgSelected.getBackground();

d.setColorFilter(setNewFilter)

// Remove the filter by setting it as null.

d.setColorFilter(null);
```

Comment: instead of highlighting default image i would like to highlight my own image

Comment: What is the big deal with that? If you wish to highlight image2, get drawable of image2 and set filter in Image1 onclick listener!

Comment: can u explain with small ex of how can i declare 2nd activities img view in 1 st activity onclick?

Comment: Now i understand you question after reading that second time. sorry for misunderstanding. U can also use this in your second activity and pass any reference using intent and set the filter as like as you want.